# Mysql count with no duplicates

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I have to 2 tables in my database. 
First one is `author` contains `(int author_id, text name_of_author)`.
Second one is `book` contains `(int book_id, int author_id, text name_of_book, text genre)`.
They related by author_id;

I'm trying to get a query, that will give me list of `genre` without duplicates, and number of authors who have written in this `genre`.

It should look something like this:

```
    GENRE  NAME_OF_AUTHERS
     novel       12
     poems       4
     fantasy     20 
     ...         ..
etc..
```

I try to do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.GENRE, COUNT(B.NAME_OF_AUTHOR) FROM BOOK AS A
LEFT JOIN AUTHOR AS B
ON A.AUTHOR_ID = B.AUTHOR.ID;
```

But it gives me wrong result.

Comment: well...what results do you get? :)

Comment: @user3364458, i think your doing some mistake in table format, you are give a name like name_of_authers. But, i think no_of_authers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need count of authors for every genre, doesn't this simple query work?

```
mysql> select count(author_id), genre from boook group by genre;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(A.NAME_OF_AUTHOR), 
    B.GENRE FROM AUTHOR AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    BOOK AS B 
ON 
    A.AUTHOR_ID = B.AUTHOR.ID
GROUP BY 
    B.GENRE;
```

If it is not working, publish the data model and the error or result you get from DB.